# вывести числа от min до max?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть функция, в нее заходит число(78),нужно увеличивать это число до тех пор пока оно не станет равно (260), максимально-прибавляемое число должно быть то что зашло в функцию(78). С этими числами примерно так:78 78 78 26. Сама задача такая, когда человек вводит число в инпут, ему должны показать варианты чисел до максимального (260), или др. пример(ввел 50, должны вывестись 50 50 50 50 50 10 / 52 52 52 52 52), главное еще то что минимальное число увеличения - то что было введено. Я подозреваю что решение куда проще чем я тут расписал, но сломал уже всю голову в поисках него. У кого есть идея как это можно решить, подкиньте пожалуйста! Заранее благодарю за уделенное мне время

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let func = (dividend, divider) => {    
    let wholeNumber = parseInt(dividend / divider);
    let remainder = dividend - divider * wholeNumber;

   return (divider + ' ').repeat(wholeNumber) + (remainder === 0 ? '' : remainder);
   //return Array(wholeNumber).fill(divider).join(' ') + (remainder === 0 ? '' : ' ' + remainder);
}

console.log(func(260, 78));
console.log(func(260, 50));
console.log(func(260, 52));
```

Comment: Дядька ты гений! работаю как надо! что делает parseInt тут объясни пожалуйста

Comment: Удаляет остаток от деления, ведь он может быть больше 0

Comment: сразу вопрос пока ты здесь, мне нужно каждое из чисел вывести в отдельные инпуты, направь плиз?

Comment: @НикитаРешетняк Если ответ правильный - не забудьте поставить галочку что это решение.

Comment: @НикитаРешетняк ну тут тогда надо чуть модифицировать. в функции положить все числа в массив и вернуть его. А потом уже в цикле пройтись по массиву и создавать html разметку в виде "инпут  с числом", конкатенируя эту разметку в одну большую строку и потом вывести куда-либо. вернуть массив можно будет так: `let arr = Array(wholeNumber).fill(divider); if (remainder !== 0 ) arr.push(remainder); return arr;`

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function devideWithRemainder(d, n = 260){
    return [...Array.from({length:n/d},()=>d),n%d].filter(e=>e!=0).join();
}

console.log(devideWithRemainder(52));
console.log(devideWithRemainder(50));
console.log(devideWithRemainder(78));
```